# How to break loops and assign parameters to array object

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

1. The loop should stop if I enter other numbers but it still looping.
2. There is an error to set information to the employee object. How actually it is supposed to write?

```java
System.out.println("Enter '1' to add employee's information:");

int add = s.nextInt();

while(add==1){

   for (int i=0; i<=employees.length; i++){

       System.out.println("Enter the name :");
       String newName = s.next();

       System.out.println("Enter the IC number :");
       String newIC = s.next();

       System.out.println("Enter the department :");
       String newdept = s.next();

       employees[i] = new Employee();
       employees[i].setEmployee(newName, newIC, newdept);

       System.out.println("Enter '1' to add employee's information:");
       add = s.nextInt();
     }
}
```

the result is for the loop can stop and we can set information for the object.

Answer (score 1):

The key is the following construct:

```
while(add==1){
  for (int i=0; i<=employees.length; i++){
    // Code
    add = s.nextInt();
  }
}
```

Look at what you specified here:

- Check if add is 1
- Go through all employee elements
- - Do something
- - Set add to another value
- Once all employees have been processed, start over

Your add variable does not play any role during your `for (i=0...)` loop, it always executes in full.

You may wish to switch the `while` and `for`statement around, or simply use something like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
   if (add != 1) break;
   // ...
   add = s.nextInt()
 }
```

As a side note, you need to check `i < employees.length` to avoid an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. The length is the first invalid index, after all.

Welcome to StackOverflow, and keep on hacking away.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the break clausule but is not recommended, for example like this:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {

   // your code
   if (add != 1){
        break;
   }
   add = s.nextInt()
 }
```

Is better if you exit from the loop using a good condition in your while.